# Execute multiple espresso methods with adb

Tags: java, android, adb, testcase, android-espresso

From the espresso docs : Selecting a subset of tests is done this way

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo1,com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo2#bar3 com.android.demo.app.tests/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Q1. Is there a way to execute multiple subsets of test so fro example I want to run bar3 and bar4 of the same class.

I tried this but didnt work :

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo1,com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo2#bar3#bar4 com.android.demo.app.tests/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Q2. Also what about executing subsets of test cases by their names in a package level so from different classes.

I am doing a model based testing project so I will be executing these cases based on the paths given.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo1,com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo2#bar3,com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo2#bar4 com.android.demo.app.tests/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

You could either use annotations to run a subset of test cases or create test suites.